# NullPointerException on WebDriver using POM and Page Factory

Tags: selenium-webdriver, java

I'm getting a NullPointerException on the Registration and BasePage classes for the driver variable. In BaseTest, I initialized the Webdriver with ChromeDriver and in the RegisterTest, it extends the BaseTest so I don't need to initialize it again.

So I thought if I pass the driver over to the Registration Class, it should be able to use the driver. Not sure if I'm missing something or am doing something wrong.

```
public class BaseTest {
    public ExtentLoggerReporter logger;
    public ExtentReports extent;
    public ExtentTest report;
    public WebDriver driver;
    
 
  @BeforeTest
  public void startReport() {
      logger = new ExtentLoggerReporter(Config.REPORT_OUTPUT_PATH + this.getClass().getSimpleName());
      extent = new ExtentReports();
      extent.attachReporter(logger);
      report = extent.createTest(this.getClass().getSimpleName());
      startBrowser(Config.BROWSER);
  }
  
  @AfterTest
  public void endReport() {
      extent.flush();
      driver.close();
  }
  
  private void startBrowser(String browserType) {     
      if(browserType.equals("CHROME")) {
          WebDriverManager.chromedriver().setup(); 
          ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
          options.addArguments("start-maximized"); 
          options.addArguments("enable-automation"); 
          options.addArguments("--no-sandbox"); 
          options.addArguments("--disable-infobars");
          options.addArguments("--disable-dev-shm-usage");
          options.addArguments("--disable-browser-side-navigation"); 
          options.addArguments("--disable-gpu"); 
          driver = new ChromeDriver(options); 
          driver.get(Config.URL);
          report.log(Status.INFO, "Opening Google Chrome Browser and navigating to URL");
      }
  }
```

```
public class RegisterTest extends BaseTest {
    
    private Registration register = new Registration(driver, report);
    
    @Test
    public void negativeTestEmail() {       
        String email1 = "test";
        report.log(Status.INFO, "Entering email -> <b>" + email1 + "</b> and clicking on Create an Account to verify error message");
        register.setEmailField(email1);
        register.clickCreateAccount();
        
        String expectedErrorMsg = "Invalid email address";
        report.log(Status.INFO, "Expected Error Message -> " + expectedErrorMsg);
        report.log(Status.INFO, "Actual Error Message -> " + register.createEmailError.getText());
        if(register.verifyIfEquals(register.createEmailError, expectedErrorMsg)) {
            report.log(Status.PASS, "The Email Address error message matches both the expected and actual");
        }
        else {
            report.log(Status.FAIL, "The Email Address error message DOES NOT match the expected and actual");
        }
    }
}
```

```
public class BasePage {
    public WebDriver driver;
    public ExtentTest report;
    
    public BasePage() { }
     
    public BasePage(WebDriver driver, ExtentTest report) {
        this.driver = driver;
        this.report = report;
        PageFactory.initElements(driver, this);
    }
    
    public void waitUntilElementIsVisible(WebElement locator) {
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(locator));
    }
    
    public void waitUntilElementIsClickable(WebElement locator) {
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(locator));
    }
    
    public boolean isElementPresent(WebElement locator) {
        if(locator.isDisplayed())
            return true;
        else 
            return false;
    }
    
    public boolean verifyIfEquals(WebElement locator, String expectedTxt) {
        if(isElementPresent(locator)) {
            String actualTxt = locator.getText();
            if(expectedTxt.equals(actualTxt))
                return true;
            else 
                return false;
        }
        else 
            return false;
    }
}
```

```
public class Registration extends BasePage {
        
    @FindBy(className = "login")
    WebElement loginBtn;  
    
    @FindBy(id = "email_create")
    WebElement emailInput;
    
    @FindBy(id = "SubmitCreate")
    WebElement createAccountBtn;
    
    @FindBy(xpath = "//*[@id=\"create_account_error\"]/ol/li")
    public WebElement createEmailError;
    
    public Registration(WebDriver driver, ExtentTest report) {
        super(driver, report);
    }
    
    public void setEmailField(String email) {
        waitUntilElementIsVisible(emailInput);
        emailInput.sendKeys(email);
    }
    
    public void clickCreateAccount() {
        waitUntilElementIsClickable(createAccountBtn);
        createAccountBtn.click();
    }

    public void goToSignInPage() {
        loginBtn.click();
    }
    
}
```

Stack Trace

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.base/java.util.Objects.requireNonNull(Objects.java:221)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.FluentWait.<init>(FluentWait.java:106)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait.<init>(WebDriverWait.java:85)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait.<init>(WebDriverWait.java:45)
    at pages.BasePage.waitUntilElementIsVisible(BasePage.java:25)
    at pages.Registration.setEmailField(Registration.java:34)
    at tests.RegisterTest.negativeTestEmail(RegisterTest.java:19)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:134)
    at org.testng.internal.TestInvoker.invokeMethod(TestInvoker.java:597)
    at org.testng.internal.TestInvoker.invokeTestMethod(TestInvoker.java:173)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodRunner.runInSequence(MethodRunner.java:46)
    at org.testng.internal.TestInvoker$MethodInvocationAgent.invoke(TestInvoker.java:816)
    at org.testng.internal.TestInvoker.invokeTestMethods(TestInvoker.java:146)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:146)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:128)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1540)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:766)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:587)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:384)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:378)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:337)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:286)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:53)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:96)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1187)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1109)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1039)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1007)
    at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:115)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:251)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:77)
```

Comment: Can you share the error stacktrace?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In class `RegisterTest.java` you should not initialize the class outside the testng annotations

Initialize the class `Registration register = new Registration(driver, report);` inside the `@Beforetest` annotation so that your class `BaseTest` will be as shown below

```
        public class BaseTest {
            public ExtentLoggerReporter logger;
            public ExtentReports extent;
            public ExtentTest report;
            public WebDriver driver;
            public Registration register;
            
         
          @BeforeTest
          public void startReport() {
              logger = new ExtentLoggerReporter(Config.REPORT_OUTPUT_PATH + this.getClass().getSimpleName());
              extent = new ExtentReports();
              extent.attachReporter(logger);
              report = extent.createTest(this.getClass().getSimpleName());
              startBrowser(Config.BROWSER);
          }
          
          @AfterTest
          public void endReport() {
              extent.flush();
              driver.close();
          }
          
          private void startBrowser(String browserType) {     
              if(browserType.equals("CHROME")) {
                  WebDriverManager.chromedriver().setup(); 
                  ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
                  options.addArguments("start-maximized"); 
                  options.addArguments("enable-automation"); 
                  options.addArguments("--no-sandbox"); 
                  options.addArguments("--disable-infobars");
                  options.addArguments("--disable-dev-shm-usage");
                  options.addArguments("--disable-browser-side-navigation"); 
                  options.addArguments("--disable-gpu"); 
                  driver = new ChromeDriver(options); 
                  driver.get(Config.URL);
                  report.log(Status.INFO, "Opening Google Chrome Browser and navigating to URL");
                  //intializing Registration class
                  register = new Registration(driver, report);          
         }
     }
```

And your `Register.java` will be as shown below

```
public class RegisterTest extends BaseTest {
    
   //private Registration register = new Registration(driver, report);
    
    @Test
    public void negativeTestEmail() {       
        String email1 = "test";
        report.log(Status.INFO, "Entering email -> <b>" + email1 + "</b> and clicking on Create an Account to verify error message");
        register.setEmailField(email1);
        register.clickCreateAccount();
        
        String expectedErrorMsg = "Invalid email address";
        report.log(Status.INFO, "Expected Error Message -> " + expectedErrorMsg);
        report.log(Status.INFO, "Actual Error Message -> " + register.createEmailError.getText());
        if(register.verifyIfEquals(register.createEmailError, expectedErrorMsg)) {
            report.log(Status.PASS, "The Email Address error message matches both the expected and actual");
        }
        else {
            report.log(Status.FAIL, "The Email Address error message DOES NOT match the expected and actual");
        }
    }
}
```

And i don't know the purpose of using the constructor parameter`report` in the class `BasePage.java`.

Hope this will fix the issue

Comment: Thank you it does work now. So I'm going to have multiple pages so do I need to initialize all those pages in the BaseTest, like how Registration is done. I added the constructor parameter report because incase if I need to log any info from the BasePage but I am going to remove it since all the tests will be in the Test classes

Comment: Please upvote by clicking on the up arrow near the answer or mark it as accepted by clicking on the check mark near the [answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86978/how-do-i-accept-an-answer-on-stackoverflow/86979#86979) if it helped you

Comment: Yeah you need to initialize in this way. But i suggest this is not proper way of `POM` implementation maintain separate class for test which should be under `src/test/java` and your element(contains your page locators and its function),base(your browser initialization reading configs acts as parent for all classes) and util class(for report generation,excel reading acts like a helper) which should be under `src/main/java`

Comment: I got it now, I had put everything under ```src/test/java``` and created packages, i'll only keep the tests there and move everything else to the main. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

as far as i know , you dont need to create a constructor in your base class. you need to have the variable declared. now from another class , you would be extending the base class. in that class you need to have a constructor create and pass driver as a variable.

What happens is from base class the driver gets initialized and then executes the steps in base class. now after a while as you called some scripts from another class , the driver is transferred to that class (register class). the driver here becomes nullfied as you are not handling over the session control to the new class.

So create a constructor in register class.something like this.
public Registration(WebDriver driver)
{
this.driver=driver;
}

Comment: In the Registration Class, I do have a constructor already that passes the WebDriver driver and called the super method